# Scrolling seems to add an unwanted chunk into my kill ring

Tags: init-file, copy-paste, debugging, scrolling, kill-ring

Anybody know why this may be occurring?

Here is an outline of how I recreate the issue...

- I copy or kill something to my kill ring.
- I scroll up or down with the mouse.
- I then yank and get an unexpected chunk of code
- Pressing `M-y` steps back one position in the kill ring and I get what I wanted to yank.

Here is my config file. Something in there must be doing it I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your config file.  But instead of posting it, do this: Start from `emacs -Q`, that is, with no init file. If you do not see the problematic behavior, then do this:

Recursively bisect your init file (by commenting-out blocks of code), until you narrow the problem down to find just what is causing it. You can use `comment-region` to comment out code: first 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8 of the code, etc.  Use `C-u` with `comment-region` to uncomment.

Another thing you can try, but don't bother until you have narrowed things down (and at that point you probably will not need to try this) is to use `M-x debug-on-entry kill-new`, to see what code is pushing the unexpected entries to your `kill-ring`. Just look at the backtrace to see what is happening, or step through the debugger using `d`, if you want. Use `q` to exit the debugger. Use `M-x cancel-debug-on-entry` to cancel using the debugger.

Comment: Thank you Drew. Helpful outline for debugging. I will report back with findings.